# Local source of Terraform AWS provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

> **What specific syntax needs to be used in the example below in order for Terraform to source the AWS provider from a given path in the local file system instead of requesting a cloud copy from the remote Terraform Registry?**

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = var._region
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_access_key
}
```

Something like `src=C:\path\to\terraform\aws\provider\binary`

I recall Mitchel Hashimoto explaining that this is a new feature during HashiConf, but I cannot seem to find documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set it in the CLI configuration as described [in the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/cli-config.html#provider-installation):

```
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/usr/share/terraform/providers"
    include = ["example.com/*/*"]
  }
  direct {
    exclude = ["example.com/*/*"]
  }
}
```